# Find new limits of integration - triple integration, how to proceed?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I am dealing with following type of task:

$$\int^{2}_{-2}dx\int^{0}_{-\sqrt{4-x^2}}dy\int^{\sqrt{4-x^2-y^2}}_{-\sqrt{4-x^2-y^2}}f(x,y,z)dz$$

I have to change the follwing integral into the form: $$dz, dy, f(x,y,z) dx$$
with new limits.

How to proceed with task like that? I've got many tasks similar to this one, with different order of integration, but how do we solve this? I would be truly grateful for step by step explanation.

Comment: change coordinate systems - this looks like either spherical or cylindrical polars would be necessary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$x=\rho\cos\theta\sin\phi$$
$$y=\rho\sin\theta\sin\phi$$
$$z=\rho\cos\phi$$
$$\left|\frac{\partial(x,y,z)}{\partial(\rho,\theta,\phi)}\right|=\rho^2\sin\phi$$
$$-\sqrt{4-{{x}^{2}}-{{y}^{2}}}\le z\le \sqrt{4-{{x}^{2}}-{{y}^{2}}}\Leftrightarrow \left\{ \begin{align}
  & 0\le \rho \le 2 \\ 
 & 0\le \phi \le \pi  \\ 
\end{align} \right.$$

$$\left\{ \begin{align}
  & -\sqrt{4-{{x}^{2}}}\le y\le 0 \\ 
 & \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\Leftrightarrow \,\pi \le \theta  \\ 
 & -2\le x\le 2 \\ 
\end{align} \right.\le 2\pi $$
we have 
$$I=\int_{\pi }^{2\pi }{\int_{0}^{\pi }{\int_{0}^{2}{{{\rho }^{2}}\sin \phi f(\rho \cos \theta \sin \phi ,}}}\rho \sin \theta \sin \phi ,\rho \cos \phi )d\rho d\phi d\theta$$

Comment: Why the heck do you use \, so much?? If you want that many, just type \qquad. Note that this is longer than the standard \quad which is longer than \; which is longer than \,

Comment: Good answer none the less

Comment: @Brevan Ellefsen I will use your advice